# Can't get print from label printer via USB

Tags: java, android, printers

I have Brother **QL-570 label printer** and it's Vender-id = 1273 and Product-id = 8232.
I want to take simple text print using my android app. Printer is connected to my phone with USB port. **I am not getting any error or even any result.** Below is my code.I searched for similar questions but can't get any solution.

Below is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private UsbManager mUsbManager;
    private UsbDevice mDevice;
    private UsbDeviceConnection mConnection;
    private UsbInterface mInterface;
    private UsbEndpoint mEndPoint;
    private PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
    EditText ed_txt;
    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
    private static Boolean forceCLaim = true;

    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> mDeviceList;
    Iterator<UsbDevice> mDeviceIterator;
    byte[] testBytes;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        ed_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_txt);
        Button print = (Button) findViewById(R.id.print);

        mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        mDeviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();

        if (mDeviceList.size() > 0) {
            mDeviceIterator = mDeviceList.values().iterator();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Device List Size: " + String.valueOf(mDeviceList.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usbDevice);
            String usbDevice = "";
            while (mDeviceIterator.hasNext()) {
                UsbDevice usbDevice1 = mDeviceIterator.next();
                usbDevice += "\n" +
                        "DeviceID: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceId() + "\n" +
                        "DeviceName: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceName() + "\n" +
                        "Protocol: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceProtocol() + "\n" +
                        "Product Name: " + usbDevice1.getProductName() + "\n" +
                        "Manufacturer Name: " + usbDevice1.getManufacturerName() + "\n" +
                        "DeviceClass: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceClass() + " - " + translateDeviceClass(usbDevice1.getDeviceClass()) + "\n" +
                        "DeviceSubClass: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n" +
                        "VendorID: " + usbDevice1.getVendorId() + "\n" +
                        "ProductID: " + usbDevice1.getProductId() + "\n";

                int interfaceCount = usbDevice1.getInterfaceCount();
                Toast.makeText(this, "INTERFACE COUNT: " + String.valueOf(interfaceCount), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mDevice = usbDevice1;

                Toast.makeText(this, "Device is attached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView.setText(usbDevice);
            }

            mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
            registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

            mUsbManager.requestPermission(mDevice, mPermissionIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please attach printer via USB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                print(mConnection, mInterface);
            }
        });
    }

    private void print(final UsbDeviceConnection connection, final UsbInterface usbInterface) {
        final String test = ed_txt.getText().toString() + "\n\n";
        testBytes = test.getBytes();
        if (usbInterface == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "INTERFACE IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (connection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "CONNECTION IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (forceCLaim == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "FORCE CLAIM IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, forceCLaim);
            try {
                byte[] cut_paper = {0x1D, 0x56, 0x41, 0x10};

                int x = connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, testBytes, testBytes.length, 500);
                //int transfered = connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, cut_paper, cut_paper.length, 50000);
                //int iRes2 = connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, testBytes, 18432, 500);//receive data

                /*byte[] init = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
                int x = connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint,init, init.length, 100);*/


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Amount of data trnasferred " + x,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                connection.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Error ==> " + e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alert(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            /*Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        byte[] cut_paper = {0x1D, 0x56, 0x41, 0x10};
                        int transfered = connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, testBytes, testBytes.length, 50000);
                        //connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, cut_paper, cut_paper.length, 0);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Amount of data trnasferred " + transfered,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Error ==> " + e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.run();*/
        }
    }


    final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        if (device != null) {
                            //call method to set up device communication
                            mInterface = device.getInterface(0);
                            mEndPoint = mInterface.getEndpoint(1);// 0 IN and  1 OUT to printer.
                            mConnection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);
                            alert(mInterface.getEndpoint(0).toString());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"==> " + mInterface.getEndpoint(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "PERMISSION DENIED FOR THIS DEVICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };


    private String translateDeviceClass(int deviceClass) {

        switch (deviceClass) {

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_APP_SPEC:
                return "Application specific USB class";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_AUDIO:
                return "USB class for audio devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CDC_DATA:
                return "USB class for CDC devices (communications device class)";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_COMM:
                return "USB class for communication devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CONTENT_SEC:
                return "USB class for content security devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CSCID:
                return "USB class for content smart card devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HID:
                return "USB class for human interface devices (for example, mice and keyboards)";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HUB:
                return "USB class for USB hubs";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_MASS_STORAGE:
                return "USB class for mass storage devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_MISC:
                return "USB class for wireless miscellaneous devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PER_INTERFACE:
                return "USB class indicating that the class is determined on a per-interface basis";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PHYSICA:
                return "USB class for physical devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PRINTER:
                return "USB class for printers";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_STILL_IMAGE:
                return "USB class for still image devices (digital cameras)";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_VENDOR_SPEC:
                return "Vendor specific USB class";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_VIDEO:
                return "USB class for video devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_WIRELESS_CONTROLLER:
                return "USB class for wireless controller devices";

            default:
                return "Unknown USB class!";
        }
    }

    private void alert(String msg){
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg);
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

**acitvity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usbDevice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:hint="Enter text to print" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/print"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="print" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**@xml/devices.xml**

```
<resources>
     <usb-device vendor-id="1273" product-id="8232" />
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.printer">

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/devices" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```